# how to create a new column from an existing one in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new in data science and I am having troubles cleaning a particular dataset.

The dataset has 34,500 rows, below is a sample of the column I want to clean:

| price |
| --- |
| $40,000 |
| N22,000,000 |
| $10,000 |

I want to create a new column that would give me the prices in Naira(N) and also convert prices in USD($) to Naira(N) using this formula - (amount in USD*480) on the same new column.

for example: The new column name be price_new, the first row would be 40,000 * 480 = 22,500,000. the second column would be 22,000,000 since its already in Naira(N) and so on. The new table should look like below:

| price | price_new |
| --- | --- |
| $40,000 | 40,000*480 = 19,200,000 |
| N22,000,000 | 22,000,000 |
| $10,000 | 10,000*480 = 4,800,000 |

I tried using this code but kept getting key error:

```
df['price_new'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: df['price'] if 'Per Year' in df['price'] else df['price'])
```

what is the right way to do this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you run `apply` on `df['price']` then using `df['price']` inside function in `apply` is useless because it gives full column instead of single value which you already have in `x`. Besides: if `apply` gives you single value in x` then function should also return single value but you returns `df['price']` which is full column. Better create normal function and use `apply(normal_function)` and then in normal function you can use `print()` to see what you have in variables - so you can debug it with `print()` (it is called `print debuging`)

Answer (score 2):

```
pat = r'.*([$N])(\d+[.]?\d*).*'

def repl(x):
    num = {'$':480, 'N':1}.get(x.group(1))
    return str(float(x.group(2)) * num)

df['new_price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace(pat, repl).astype(float)

df
         price   new_price
0      $40,000  19200000.0
1  N22,000,000  22000000.0
2      $10,000   4800000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

First you could create normal function - ie `def convert(value):` - and use it as `apply(convert)` - and this way you can add `print()` in function to see what you have in variables

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['$40,000', 'N22,000,000', '$10,000']})

def convert(value):
    print('value:', value)
    return value

df['price_new'] = df['price'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

And later you can add code in `convert` and use `print()` to see if it gives correct values.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['$40,000', 'N22,000,000', '$10,000']})

def convert(value):
    print('value:', value)

    value = value.replace(',', '')
    print('value:', value)

    char = value[0]
    value = int(value[1:])
    print('value:', value, 'char:', char)

    if char == '$':
        value *= 480

    print('value:', value)
    print('---')
 
    return value
    #return value

df['price_new'] = df['price'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

And this way you can see if code works correctly

Result:

```
value: $40,000
value: $40000
value: 40000 char: $
value: 19200000
---
value: N22,000,000
value: N22000000
value: 22000000 char: N
value: 22000000
---
value: $10,000
value: $10000
value: 10000 char: $
value: 4800000
---

         price  price_new
0      $40,000   19200000
1  N22,000,000   22000000
2      $10,000    4800000
```

And later you can remove `print()` to get your final code.

Eventually you could try to make it shorter - but shorter example you have in other answer so I skip it. And I still have some ideas how to rebuild this code.

---

**EDIT:**

If you will have more currencies then you may use dictionary

```
exchange = {'$': 480, 'N': 1, '€': 100, '£': 200}
```

with

```
    if char in exchange:
        value *= exchange[char]
```

and then code will be

```
exchange = {'$': 480, 'N': 1, '€': 100, '£': 200}

def convert(value):
    print('value:', value)

    value = value.replace(',', '')
    print('value:', value)

    char = value[0]
    value = int(value[1:])
    print('value:', value, 'char:', char)

    if char in exchange:
        print('exchange:', exchange[char])
        value *= exchange[char]
    else:
        print('exchange: UNKNOWN')    

    print('value:', value)
    print('---')
 
    return value
```

But problem is what to do with unknown currency.

There can be also problem if currency uses longer name - `USD`, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

Version which converts `USD`. It uses `key` from dictionary and check `value.startswith(key)`

It also uses special construction `for/break/else` to detect unknown currency. This `else` has the same indentation as `for`, not as `if`, and it is executed if `break` was not used in `for`-loop.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'price': ['$40,000', 'N22,000,000', '$10,000', '€2,000',
                  '£300', 'USD10,000', '¥100']
     })

exchange = {'$': 480, 'N': 1, '€': 100, '£': 200, 'USD': 480}

def convert(value):
    print('value:', value)

    value = value.replace(',', '')
    print('value:', value)

    for key in exchange:
        if value.upper().startswith(key):
             print('exchange:', exchange[key])
             # skip name 
             value = int(value[len(key):])
             # calculate new value
             value *= exchange[key]
             break  # exit loop because there is no need to check other keys
    else:  # it is part of `for/break/else`, not `if/else`
        # executed if `break` was not used in `for`-loop 
        print('exchange: *** UNKNOWN ***')
        
    print('value:', value)
    print('---')
 
    return value
    #return value

df['price_new'] = df['price'].apply(convert)

print(df)
```

Comment: I love this answer because you not only answered the question, but imparted some of the concepts behind creating a good function too :) kudos!

Comment: @Javier thnak you. Answer show how I build code for this answer - step by step. Now I added code with more currency `exchange = {'$': 480, 'N': 1, '€': 100, '£': 200}` and I thinking what to do with names like `USD`.